# Show the catalog is too slow in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I'm working on an app that has a product catalog with a n-level category tree.

I have the next structure:

```
Category 1
--Category 1.1
----Category 1.1.1
------Product 1.1.1.1
------Product 1.1.1.2
----Product 1.1.1
--Category 1.2
----Product 1.2.1
--Product 1.1
```

And I need something like a flat array:

```
Category 1
Category 1.1
Category 1.1.1
Product 1.1.1.1
Product 1.1.1.2
Product 1.1.1
Category 1.2
Product 1.2.1
Product 1.1
```

But the problem is that I need too much queries and too much time to generate this (I have 700 products and 200 categories more or less and it takes about 846 queries and 2100 ms to execute them). I can add more joins, but the execution time grows significantly. I'm working with translatable entities.

Any idea to minimize the queries number and the execution time? Categories has a self-relationship and a relationship with products.

I think that an option can be to get all categories and make a ordered tree and later redo the flat array again, but I don't know if it could be the best option...

Thank you in advance for any help!

EDIT:
This is my function to generate the "flat" array.

```
public function generateCategoriesTree($categories, $result = array()) {
    $tempResult = array();
    if(count($categories)) {
        foreach($categories as $k => $v) {
            $tempResult[] = $v;
            if(count($v->getCategories())) {
                $temp = $this->generateCategoriesTree($v->getCategories(), $result);
                foreach($temp as $kk => $vv) {
                    $tempResult[] = $vv;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return array_merge($result, $tempResult);
}
```

But the problem is not here, the problem is when I trying to acces to the second level of the tree, when call to the method getcategories, that execute a query in the database.

**UPDATE**

With this solution, I reduced the number of queries from 700 to 100 and the execution time from 2100ms to 350ms. I think that it could be enough for now, becouse this actions is used a couple per hour.

```
if ($this->isGranted('ROLE_EMPLOYEE') || $currentUser->isXXXXXXSeller()) {
    $XXXXXXCategories = $em->getRepository('CatalogBundle:Category')->getMainCategoriesByBrand(1);
    if(is_array($XXXXXXCategories)) {
        $categoriesXXXXXX = $this->get('core_tools')->generateCategoriesTree($XXXXXXCategories);
        $categories = new ArrayCollection(
            array_merge($categories->toArray(), $categoriesXXXXXX)
        );
    }
}
$categoriesToShow = array();
$products = $em->getRepository('CatalogBundle:Product')->getAllOrderedByPosition();
if(is_array($products) && is_array($categories)) {
    foreach($categories as $category) {
        $categoriesToShow["c_".$category->getId()] = array(
            "category"  => $category,
            "products"  => array(),
        );
    }
    foreach($products as $product) {
        if($product->getCategories()) {
            foreach($product->getCategories() as $productCategory) {
                if(array_key_exists("c_".$productCategory->getCategory()->getId(), $categoriesToShow)) {
                    $categoriesToShow["c_".$productCategory->getCategory()->getId()]['products'][] = $product;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you show how you generate those two structures now?

Comment: @Micha I added the function to generate the category tree.

Comment: Do you need entities as a return values or just arrays?

Comment: Array of entities, because I need print a table in the twig template, to show a full list of products.

Comment: I am not quite sure this adds to your performance, but have you tryied "EAGER" fetching your entities? this would be an annotation example:  @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Phonenumber", mappedBy="user", indexBy="id", fetch="EAGER")

Comment: I didn't use EAGER, I will try it. For now, I make two functions, one for the categories and another one for products. Later, with two loops, I join the products with the categories and now I only have 102 queries and 350ms of execution time. I think that it could be enough because this action is not usual on the website, perhaps a couple per hour.

Comment: Do you use Doctrine? Did you try to use Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY and fetch all categories with one query?

Comment: @Srdjan No, I didn't know about that. I'm going to get information about HYDRATE_ARRAY. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the catalog doesn't change very often (ie: more than every few seconds) - then do the hard work once, and then cache the output ready to be used instantly.

When the catalog changes - rebuild the cache.

Comment: could you give a code example how to implement this?

Comment: I though about this option, and I think that could be the best option. I'm going to try to cache an array with the options that I need.

Comment: I finally did a function to generate a catalog json string and I stored in the database. Every time that you make changes in the catalog, you call that function. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL you might like to consider the "Nested Sets" model to store your category hierarchy. The complexity of your SELECTs will usually stay constant no matter how many levels your category tree has. There are Doctrine extensions available that help you setting it up (e.g. https://github.com/blt04/doctrine2-nestedset).

If you are using a DBS supporting hierarchical queries you can consider using them (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL).